Why formatted date with carbon is invalid?
Why in In laravel 11,  PHP 8.2 app running code
$minDay = CurrencyHistory::select(DB::raw('MIN(day) as min_day'))->first()->min_day;
\Log::info($minDay);
\Log::info(Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($minDay))->format('j F, Y'));

I see results :
[2024-10-05 07:30:08] local.INFO: 2024-09-28
[2024-10-05 07:30:08] local.INFO: 27 September, 2024

So the min day is 2024-09-28, but resulting value on a form I have is 27 September, 2024
In CurrencyHistory Model I have :
protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime', 'updated_at' => 'datetime', 'value' => HistoryMoney::class, 'day' => 'date'
    ];

Tracing SQL I have :
   SELECT MIN(day)     AS min_day
    FROM `currency_histories` limit 1

Which returns value 2024-09-28.
Is format 'j F, Y' invalid? With format format('d F, Y' the same result...
Which format have I to use?

The possible reason might be related to server time.

createFromTimestamp creates a date from a UTC timestamp and keeps the timezone as UTC. If your timezone is anything negative then at your midnight your UTC time falls within yesterday. To correct for timezone using createFromTimestamp then pass the 2nd parameter to specify your locale.

From Laravel 7, the date and datetime casts will serialize dates to a UTC ISO-8601. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization

This is a common missatke.
When you use Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($minDay)), a Carbon instance is created using your default timezone. If your timezone is behind UTC, the time goes backward, resulting in a date of 2024-09-27.
Update like this
$minDay = CurrencyHistory::select(DB::raw('MIN(day) as min_day'))->first()->min_day;

# Use Carbon::parse
$formattedDate = Carbon::parse($minDay)->format('j F, Y');

